# ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 10 and 1

Tags: keras, deep-learning, mnist, shap

I was trying to implement shap DeepExplainer (DeepSHAP) module with the help of MNIST Dataset. But i am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 10 and 1. Shapes are [?,10] and [?,1]. for gradients_7/dense_2_1/Softmax_grad/gradients/gradients_7/dense_2_1/Softmax_grad/truediv_grad/Select_1 (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [?,1], [?,10], [?,10].

The error is in the line:
`shap_values = e.shap_values(x_test[1:5])`

Full code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=epochs,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

import shap
import numpy as np

# select a set of background examples to take an expectation over
background = x_train[np.random.choice(x_train.shape[0], 100, replace=False)]

# explain predictions of the model on three images
e = shap.DeepExplainer(model, background)
shap_values = e.shap_values(x_test[1:5])
shap.image_plot(shap_values, -x_test[1:5])
```

Answer (score -1):

Which Keras version you are using? You can print from your code `keras.__version__`

When I imported keras under `Tensorflow`, your code worked as expected. One of the major change is using `adam` optimizer which works better in your case as it is able to improve accuracy within few epochs. I tried `Adadelta` but it was slowly optimizing. check the performance yourself.

Check the following code for small modifications (not much). All i did was to import modules under `Tensorflow` as `keas 2.3.1` was throwing some other error.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

batch_size = 256
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape,))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),#tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          steps_per_epoch = x_train.shape[0]//batch_size,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=epochs,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=(x_test, y_test),validation_steps=x_test.shape[0]//batch_size)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Comment: Er, question was about SHAP, and not about building the model...