# SHAP ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 2 and 1. Shapes are [?,2] and [?,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, valueerror, dimensions, shap

Based on a previously trained feed-forward network, I tried to use SHAP to get the feature importance. I followed all the steps described in the documentation but I am still receiving the following error

`ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 2 and 1. Shapes are [?,2] and [?,1]`

The following code produces a reproduciple example that has the same error.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import shap

# Train_x data creation
train_x = pd.DataFrame({
    'v1': randint(2, 20, 1489),
    'v2': randint(50, 200, 1489),
    'v3': randint(30, 90, 1489),
    'v4': randint(100, 150, 1489)
})

# Train_y data creation
train_y = randint(0, 2, 1489)

# One-hot encoding as I use categorical cross-entropy
train_y = to_categorical(train_y, num_classes=2)

# Start construction of a DNN Sequential model.
model = Sequential()

# First input layer with a dropout and batch normalization layer following
model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=train_x.shape[1]))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# Use the Adam optimizer
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

# Fit model
hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=128, shuffle=False, verbose=2)

# SHAP calculation
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, train_x)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(train_x[:500].values)
```

where I have an input shape of `(None, 4)` and a softmax activation function at the end with 2 neurons as I use it for binary classification. The `train_x` data on the following code snippet are a pandas data frame of shape `(1489, 4)`.

I tried to change the `train_x` shape but I had a similar error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For binary classification you only need one output neuron (one is constrained by the other since the sum of softmax probs = 1).

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153184/valueerror-dimension-1-in-both-shapes-must-be-equal-but-are-10-and-1

Comment: @jtlz2 I am using the categorical cross-entropy, which is the same but this isn't related with my question. Furthermore, the questions are similar but in the other question, the error is generated from the documentation example and not from a pre-trained network.

Comment: A [reprex] may help.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov please find an edit with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below a working example for binary classification with TF:

```
from numpy.random import randint
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import shap
import tensorflow
print(shap.__version__, "\n",tensorflow.__version__)

# Train_x data creation
train_x = pd.DataFrame({
    'v1': randint(2, 20, 1489),
    'v2': randint(50, 200, 1489),
    'v3': randint(30, 90, 1489),
    'v4': randint(100, 150, 1489)
})

# Train_y data creation
train_y = randint(0, 2, 1489)

# One-hot encoding as I use categorical cross-entropy
train_y = to_categorical(train_y, num_classes=2)

# Start construction of a DNN Sequential model.
model = Sequential()

# First input layer with a dropout and batch normalization layer following
model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=train_x.shape[1]))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# Use the Adam optimizer
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

# model.summary()

# Fit model
hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=128, shuffle=False, verbose=0)

# SHAP calculation
shap.explainers._deep.deep_tf.op_handlers["AddV2"] = shap.explainers._deep.deep_tf.passthrough
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, train_x)

shap_values = explainer.shap_values(train_x[:500].values)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1])
```

---

```
0.38.2 
 2.2.0
```

[image]

Note couple of things:

1. Package versions (tf should be below 2.4 I believe)
2. Addition of `"AddV2"` (see discussion [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/1110))

Comment: the provided code indeed works. But in my case where I have evaluated the DNN with Tensoflow 1.14 and SHAP 0.38.2 version I still receive the error. I can't understand what I am doing wrong. I also receive the following message when I run the shap.DeepExplainer function 
```keras is no longer supported, please use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From  The name tf.keras.backend.get_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session instead.
```

Comment: My problem is that I have a saved model that was created using tensorflow.python.keras. Is there any way to use this type of saved model with SHAP without receiving the following error?